# How to combine normal font and latex font types in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, legend, font-family

I am aware of Matplotlib's `math_fontfamily` to mix family font types within the same string. I use the feature for my title and it works perfectly fine. For example:

```
ax[0].set_title(r'Total response $\tau_c/\tau$', math_fontfamily='cm')
```

mixes normal text and latex text.

Now, I would like to use the same feature for the plot legend. I am using the "label" command as in

```
ax[0].plot(x, y, label="I want normal text and latex text, eg $\tau/\gamma$")
ax[0].legend(loc='lower center')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to enable Latex rendering via Matplotlib's rcParams, e.g.:

```py
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "Helvetica"
})
```

See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/usetex.html) for more info. Note, that this requires a working Latex installation.

Comment: This changes all text in the plot (axis labels, axis ticks, title) to Latex format, which is not what I want. I want normal text everywhere except for a few math symbols in the legend